# Loading Ajax page losing styles

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, styles

I have checked the answers to other similar questions about AJAX not loading styles. None of the solutions worked for me.

Inside an AJAX call, I am loading another AJAX call into an element on the page:

```
$.ajax({
        url: site_url+'/ajax/int_rooms'
    }).done(function (data) {
        $('.rooms-sides').append(data);
    });
```

I also tried `$('.rooms-sides').load(site_url+'/ajax/int_rooms');`

When I take the HTML and put it manually into the page, it is styled and looking as expected.
When I take it and paste it right into the AJAX(which is loading successfully), it is no longer formatted correctly.

There are no errors in the console. I am using Chrome(identical results in Firefox).
If I 'inspect element', it seems that the loaded file is LOSING table tags like `<tr>`, however when I view the response from the network tab in chromes developer tools, I do in fact see the table tags being returned.

I repeat, when I use the html identically in the main file that everything is being plugged into, it works perfectly.

This HTML is being put into a php variable which is output, that is why you see $r->name.
I have tried putting it just in HTML, not in php output as well in the file and it yields the exact same error.

The HTML in question:

```
<input type='hidden' id='room_name' value='$r->name'/>
    <tr>
    <td class="action"><a href="#" title="Delete"><span class="delete">Delete</span></td>
    <td class="action"><a href="#" title="Duplicate"><span class="duplicate">Duplicate</span></td>
    <td><a href="#" title="Configure">Configure</td>
    <td>

    <div class="ui-widget">
    <select id="combobox">
    <option value="">Select one...</option>
    <option value="Kitchen">Kitchen</option>
    <option value="Bedroom">Bedroom</option>
    <option value="Living Room">Living Room</option>
    <option value="Dining Room">Dining Room</option>
    <option value="Hallway">Hallway</option>
    </select>
    </div>

    </td>
    <td>$364.14</td>
    </tr>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#room_name").remove();
    </script>
```

Comment: I don't see a `<table>` element?

Comment: The `<table>` element is already in the main page, this is being inserted already inside the `<table>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it with the help of a co-worker.

Must move the hidden input, it is breaking the table rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try applying style in that `/ajax/int_rooms` file.

Comment: No dice. I feel like there should be a better solution anyway, but I appreciate the help.